# compilation error after upgrade from VS2015 to VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, iterator

after upgrade my VC++ project from VS2015 to VS2017, no build error when built with VS2015. with VS2017 I am getting the following build error:

(217): error C2678:      binary '*': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Iter' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

The problematic line is:

```
std::vector <WeakRef <int> > vc (weakref_adaptor (v.begin()), weakref_adaptor (v.end()));
```

The WeakRef and weakref_adaptor are defined as follow:

```
template <class T>
class WeakRef
{
public:
   explicit WeakRef (T* t)
    : _ref (t)
    {}
    WeakRef (const WeakRef& r)
    : _ref (r._ref)
    {}
    WeakRef& operator = (const WeakRef& r)
    {
       _ref = r._ref;
       return *this;
     }

     ~WeakRef ()
     {
        // Quite specifically, nothing to do: certainly not deleting _ref!
     }


    T& operator * () const
    {
        return *_ref;
    }

    T* operator -> () const
    {
        return _ref;
    }

    private:
         T* _ref;
};

template < class Iterator, class Value = typename Iterator::value_type >
class weakref_adaptor_t
{
public:
    typedef typename Iterator base_iterator;

    typedef WeakRef <typename Value> value_type;
    typedef typename base_iterator::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;


    weakref_adaptor_t (const base_iterator& base)
       : _base (base)
    {};


    value_type operator * ()
    {
        return value_type (&(*_base));
    }


   private:
       base_iterator _base;
   };


   template <class Iterator>
   weakref_adaptor_t <Iterator> weakref_adaptor (const Iterator& i)
   {
     return weakref_adaptor_t <Iterator> (i);
    }

   template <class Iterator>
   weakref_adaptor_t <Iterator, const typename Iterator::value_type> 
   const_weakref_adaptor (const Iterator& i)
   {
       return weakref_adaptor_t <Iterator, const Iterator::value_type> (i);
   }
};
```

Comment: It seems some const-correctness issue were fixed between VS2015 and VS2017. I say that because you call `weakref_adaptor` with a reference to a *constant* iterator, but the `weakref_adaptor_t<...>` object it returns is for *non* constant iterators.

Comment: Is there a reason `WeakRef`'s special members are provided, not defaulted?

Comment: this appears to be a bug in VS2017

Comment: hi sp2danny, do you know any update version of VS2017 will have this bug fixed?

Comment: I just upgraded my VS2017 from version 15.8.7 to 15.9.12, still has the same problem. should I use VS2019 instead?